# What's the correct way to define a __next__ iterator method?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, iterator

Below is an iterator that given a start and a stop values it yields integers incrementing by one:

```
class Iterator:

    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self._start = self.start

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.current = self._start    
        if self.current >= self.stop:
            raise StopIteration
        self._start += 1
        return self.current
```

I see the above version used by everyone. Woudln't the following version be more readable? It also avoids the use of the `if` conditional if that's a good thing.

```
    def __next__(self):
        self.current = self._start
        while self.current < self.stop:
            self._start += 1
            return self.current
        raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Your `while` loop containing a `return` is in fact an `if`: it will never be executed more than once. So you do exactly the same, you just inverted the condition.

Comment: I tried to implement both versions and measured their speed. I did it in spyder, with python 3.6.5, using the `%timeit` magic word. When instantiating the object, I used `start=1` and `stop=1000`. The function I timed was `[x for x in object_instance]`. The `if` version gave: `846 ns ± 3.95 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`, and the `while` version: `885 ns ± 3.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`. It seems like the if version is faster.